# How to reset a Form that has TextFormField with onUserInteraction validation mode

Tags: flutter

**Minimal reproducible code:**

```dart
class FooPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<FooPage> createState() => _FooPageState();
}

class _FooPageState extends State<FooPage> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: TextFormField(
              controller: _controller,
              autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
              validator: (input) {
                if (input!.isEmpty) return 'Missing';
                if (input.length < 3) return 'Too short';
                return null;
              },
            ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              // setState(() {}); // Uncomment this line to see the problem. 
              await Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
              _formKey.currentState!.reset();
              _controller.clear();
            },
            child: Text('Clear'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Type two characters in the text field, and it will show `'Too short'` error as expected. Now, click the `Clear` button and both the form and field will reset, so far so good.

But if you uncomment the `setState` call in the code above and perform above step, then it gives `'Missing'` error. Can anyone please explain what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not looking for workarounds, like add another dummy future and then reset the form.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour in DartPad. Without the `Future.delayed()` and `setState` it works as expected.

Comment: @PeterKoltai That's why I asked the question that why is this not working with `setState`. What magic is going on?

Comment: I mean it works with `setState` as well for me.

Comment: @PeterKoltai You can then try it in IDE. I tested it on macOS, and Android and both have the same issue.